# Featured Image Not Showing in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to show a featured image in Wordpress, I've uploaded the image (put it as the smallest image possible) but when I view the blog list view (category.php) I just get the blog post header, and no image.

Anybody know how to show the image? Checked the source, and doesn't show an image at all.

Hope someone can help, would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is no code really, just added a Featured Image to a blog post, trying to get it to show

Comment: Do you see the image when you go to the post itself?

Comment: Do you know if the theme is actually able to show featured images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to setting the featured image in WP admin, you need rendering code somewhere in your template files. Something like this:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() ) ) {
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() );
}
```

I use this code in my `header.php` theme file, but you may prefer it within `page.php` or elsewhere (`category.php` seems appropriate in your case).

Check the documentation for help changing the dimensions, adding class attributes, etc. to the `<img/>` tag generated.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail