# Add a pages featured image to a foreach loop

Tags: wordpress, loops

I've got a foreach loop that is displaying a list of subpages Title, Content and URL. I can't seem to display the featured image though! Here's what I have:

```
<?php
$pageChildren = get_pages('sort_column=menu_order&hierarchical=0&child_of='.$post->ID);
if ( $pageChildren ) {
foreach ( $pageChildren as $pageChild ) {
echo '<div style="position:relative;float:left;width:100%;margin:0 0 20px 0;border-bottom:1px dashed #cdcdcd;padding:0 0 20px 0">';
//FEATURED IMAGE HERE
echo '<a class="newstitle" href="' . get_permalink($pageChild->ID) . '">' . $pageChild->post_title.'</a><br /><br />';
if (!empty($pageChild->post_content)){
        echo '<p>'.$pageChild->post_content.'</p> ';
        echo '<a class="readmore" href="' . get_permalink($pageChild->ID) . '" style="float:left">Read More &raquo;</a>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Check this . Similar question to yours. See if the answer applies to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586551/featured-image-not-showing-in-wordpress

Comment: No, when I put in the code suggested nothing gets displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID ); ?>
```

to get the post thumbnail as well page

Comment: Thank you this works brilliantly! Do you know how I could add a class to it?

Comment: ya, you can add class by follows <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID, 'type', array('class' => 'your_class')); ?>. here type maybe thumbnail and so on